# how to fetch mysql data using ajax when one input is filled

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

html

```
<input type="text" name="PName" />
<input type="text" name="PAddress" />
<input type="text" name="PCity" />
```

mysql table

```
 ________________________________________________________
| id  |PName          |  PAddress           |  PCity    |
| ----|-------------------------------------------------|
|  1  | John           |  po box no xyz      |  Florida |
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

now my question is how do i use ajax to fetch the address and city when i enter the name? any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to learn more about AJAX, PHP and Database.

Comment: umm thats not my answer ? :P ehhe

Comment: Try yourself and come back if you face any issue.

Comment: i use fetcher.php file which connects the database and gets the row in the famouse sql fetch array.

Comment: You should look for a tutorial that deals with this, basically you need a php get function which retrieves data from a database and using ajax you can use a get function that returns this information.

Comment: post your code that is giving you hard time, learn json, and js and ajax principles and maybe a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago, i did a "live" search for my project, so here is some code modified for your needs (i assume you have [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on your page).

First of all i suggest you give your inputs some id's:

```
<input type="text" name="PName" id="PName" />
<input type="text" name="PAddress" id="PAdress" />
<input type="text" name="PCity" id="PCity" />
```

After that you can bind a keyup event of PName field:

```
var searchTimeout; //Timer to wait a little before fetching the data
$("#PName").keyup(function() {
    searchKey = this.value;

    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);

    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        getUsers(searchKey);    
    }, 400); //If the key isn't pressed 400 ms, we fetch the data
});
```

The js function to fetch the data:

```
function getUsers(searchKey) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getUser.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {value: searchKey},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status) {
                $("#PAddress").val(data.userData.PAddress);
                $("#PCity").val(data.userData.PCity);
            } else {
                // Some code to run when nothing is found
            }   
        }
    });         
}
```

And ofcourse the `getUser.php` file:

```
<?php
    //... mysql connection etc.

    $response = Array();

    $response['status'] = false;

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `PAddress`, `PCity` FROM `Users` WHERE `PName` LIKE '%".$_POST['value']."%' LIMIT 1"); //Or you can use = instead of LIKE if you need a more strickt search

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
        $userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $response['userData'] = $userData;
        $response['status'] = true;            
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Good luck! ^^

Comment: why cant i get this to work ?
im using a field called idCardNo to fetch Name and permAddress. 
when i goto getUser.php?A123456 (because i changed type to GET) i get this messege. but in my html file i cant get the results
{"status":true,"userData":{"Name":"Nizar Ibrahim","permAddr":"Dhildhaaruge"}}

Comment: if you use `Name` and `permAddr` then change `$("#PAddress").val(data.userData.PAddress);` to `$("#PAddress").val(data.userData.permAddr);` and another one accordingly. And in the `SQL` change `$_POST` to `$_GET`. Oh and you should use `getUser.php?value=A123456` to get the information directly.

Comment: one little help @Arthur pls.. i couldnt get it to work still. i uploaded all code to http://intruderexists.0fees.net/index.html

database img: http://intruderexists.0fees.net/dbase.png