# how to fetch mysql data using ajax when one input is filled using function.php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

mysql table

---

|order_no  |order_name  |
| -------- |------------|
| 43423    | abc        |
??????????????????????????

now my question is how do i use ajax to fetch the order name and city when i order number ? any help is appreciated..

I have a code here:

ValidateForm.js

```
var searchTimeout; //Timer to wait a little before fetching the data
$("#order_numbr").keyup(function() {
    searchKey = this.value;

    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);

    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        getUsers(searchKey);    
    }, 400); //If the key isn't pressed 400 ms, we fetch the data
});


function getUsers(searchKey) {
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            async: false,
            data : "action=checkOrdrNum",
            url  : ajaxurl,
            dataType:"json",
             success: function(data) {
            if(data.status) {
                $("#ur_name1").val(data.userData.order_name);
            }   
        }
    }"This order number does not exist");         
}




And ofcourse the function.php file:


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_checkOrdrNum','checkOrdrNum');
add_action('wp_ajax_checkOrdrNum','checkOrdrNum');
function checkOrdrNum(){
    global $wpdb,$current_user;

     $response = Array();

    $response['status'] = false;

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `order_name` FROM `art_work_history` WHERE `order_no` LIKE '%".$_POST['value']."%' LIMIT 1"); //Or you can use = instead of LIKE if you need a more strickt search

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
        $userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $response['userData'] = $userData;
        $response['status'] = true;            
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to pass input value to the ajax

I thnk that was the only thing missing

```
function getUsers(searchKey) {
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            async: false,
            data : "action=checkOrdrNum",
            url  : ajaxurl,
            dataType:"json",
            data: {value: searchKey}, // this is the line missing
             success: function(data) {
                if(data.status) {
                $("#ur_name1").val(data.userData.order_name);
            }   
        }
    });         
}
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting? whats `data` in the `success` function?

Comment: I have 2 textbox #order_numbr and #ur_name1. I want to display the value order_name in #ur_name1 once you search correct order_no using #order_numbr.

Comment: i understood your requirement. all i need is y it is not working. what is the response you r getting from the server. what does `echo json_encode($response);` this output?

Comment: Im sorry I didnt understand. Ive been do same as  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883178/how-to-fetch-mysql-data-using-ajax-when-one-input-is-filled[/link]

Comment: hav you jus copy pasted everything from that thread?  are you opening and closing the database connections and flusing the output in php? any errors on server side? please check the logs.

Comment: yes I put the database connections in the function.php on my template wordpress and the other one is in the plugin I made ValidateForm.js

Comment: probably I dont know how to test it. Kindly check if the connection/query is ok.

Comment: you can use `log($response);` to print on serverlog.

Comment: sorry doesnt work.Last day Ive almost done but doesnt display. I posted [link] https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-use-jquery-that-display-the-record-from-the-database-25-2-2013#14737000003980831 Kindly check.